# Why are these tags removed with MGans's HtmlSanitizer?

Tags: html, xss, sanitization, html-sanitizing

I am thinking of using the `HtmlSanitizer` Nuget package by MGans for sanitizing input and output on our application. Given the below input and applying the `Sanitize()` method, the following is returned:

Input:

```
this  is my data
<p> here</p>
<script type="text/javascript"/>
<b>and here</b>
alert("something");
done here
<script type="text/javascript">alert("again");</script>
done
```

Output:

```
this  is my data
<p> here</p>

done
```

Why are the tags `<b>and here</b>`, `alert("something");` and text `done here` removed if the first `<script/>` tag is a self-closing tag with no arguments?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript"/>` would do nothing since it's-closing. Why even have it? I think it's removing the content after because it's looking for a close tag

Comment: User input my friend, anything is possible.

Comment: Rudolf then it is because it's looking for a close tag. Also I'm unsure how this is relevant to `jQuery`

Comment: My bad re the tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML4 and HTML5, `<script>` tags can't be self-closing. The self-closing tags are the [void elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#void-elements) in the spec.

When parsed, then the first `<script>` tag is treated as the opening tag, and the final `</script>` tag is its ending tag.

A browser would treat the slash as malformed input and ignore it, then execute the contents after it as JavaScript code.